# Pointer on arduino in loop function

Tags: c, pointers, arduino

I have a infinite loop function :

```
void lancementCycleSecond(void *idCycleSecond) {

  const int i = *(int *)idCycleSecond;

  float relance = RelaisCycle[i].timeOn + RelaisCycle[i].timeOff;
  Serial.println(F(" "));
  Serial.print(F(" Action on "));
  Serial.print(RelaisCycle[i].nom);
  Serial.println(F(" "));

  RelaisCycle[i].idTimer= t.pulseImmediate(RelaisCycle[i].pin, RelaisCycle[i].timeOn, LOW);
  cycles[i].idTimer1 = t.after(relance, lancementCycleSecond,(void *)&i);
  RelaisCycle[i].onOff;
}
```

i think that this line is the problem, because all work for the first time

```
t.after(relance, lancementCycleSecond,(void *)&i);
```

For the firstime `i =3`, but in the second time ( in the loop )  `i= -6092`.

I think that i made a mistake with   `(void *)&i` . I also test just `&i`

here the doc for after();

> Description
>
> Run the callback function once, after period milliseconds.
>
> Syntax
>
> t.after(period, callback, context);
>
> Parameters
>
> period: How long to wait before running the callback function, in
>   milliseconds (unsigned long) callback: The name of the callback
>   function which is called when the timer event fires (function pointer)
>   context: Context value to be passed to the callback function (void
>   pointer)
>
> Returns
>
> The ID of the Timer event (int8_t or char)

**Thank for your help.**

Comment: You're storing a pointer to a local variable with automatic storage duration. Dereferencing it after the variable's lifetime ends is undefined.

Comment: I don't know if adding `static` to `i` will solve. I'd just move it outside the function to make it "global". And... What is t?